# Can Internet Explorer 9 or 10 be installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, browser

Trying to figure out whether the Internet Explorer 10 or Internet Explorer 9 can be installed on Ubuntu or not? Has anyone tried it successfully? Can it be installed in the first place?

I have searched this topic on Google, but surprisingly did not find a single thing related to it.

Comment: I might not be the only curious one, but Why?

Comment: Depending on what you need it for, Googles' Chrome-Browsser in conjunction with an extension like "IE Tab" may be of help.

Comment: Also posted here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065413

Comment: This is not so relevant to the question, but there used to be Internet Explorer for UNIX up until 2002 (Not so certain about the year). Microsoft removed download link since, and I don't know if it could be downloaded from somewhere.

Comment: @Grizly Why? Because unfortunately IE is one of the most popular browsers and web developers have to support it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mrokii [IE Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE_Tab) actually uses part of Internet Explorer. Like Internet Explorer, the IE Tab extension for Firefox and Chrome/Chromium *only runs on Windows*.

Comment: @Cyle I don't see how supporting it means it has to be installed on Ubuntu.  Using a virtual machine is a much more sensible option..

Comment: @wim Yeah, certainly. If you happen to have some spare windows keys laying around :P